# Bash, command on remote server returns true in case of failed

Tags: bash, if-statement, ssh, command

Command executed on remote server returns true even if failed. Here is the code.

```
command="
sudo su - postgres -c 'pg_dump -Fc ${var[1]}'
"

if
ssh -n -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$username"@"${var[0]}" "$command" > "$folder_export"/"${var[0]}"/"$date"-"$time"-"${var[0]}"-"${var[1]}".dump
export_end=$date-$time
then
export=true
else
export=false
fi
```

I tried to stop postgres on remote server.
Output shows me this.

```
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "coopweb" failed: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

But if condition returns true. I don't know why.
Could be some option in ssh command wrong? Or where is the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: The script has problems and does not execute. Shellcheck produces 7 findings for your code. Please fix the script. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your statement the return code evaluated in the if expression is the return code of the assignment to the variable export_end.
One solution would be to move this assignment into the if/else branches:

```
 ...
 if ssh -n -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no "$username"@"${var[0]}" "$command" > "$folder_export"/"${var[0]}"/"$date"-"$time"-"${var[0]}"-"${var[1]}".dump
 then
   export_end=$date-$time
   export=true
 else
   export_end=$date-$time
   export=false
 fi
```

Comment: Rather than duplicating the assignment it should simply be moved outside the conditional. Otherwise spot on.

Comment: It works! Both solutions. Thanks! So problem was, that return code is generated from last command/variable assign?

Comment: Yes, as you did it, you can put a list of commands after 'if'. The exit-code of a subsequent command overwrites the exit-code of the previous command, so that the exit-code of the last command is used to evalute the if statement. In your case it is an variable assignment that always returns 0.

Comment: Just another question about this code, export_start and export_end returns me the same value, but processes starting and ending in different times. This is what I have in variable date and time: date=$(date +%Y%m%d)
time=$(date +%H%M%S).

Comment: $date and $time get the values from the point in time when you set the variables. The won't change afterwards. You may open a new question with the full code regarding the problem.